# How to check the deleted tweets?

Tags: python, python-3.x, twitter, tweepy

I have millions of tweet ID, I wanted to check whether the tweet is deleted or not.

I can crawl all the tweet ID using Tweepy and match it with previous data difference will be deleted tweets.

```
def lookup_tweets(tweet_IDs, api):
full_tweets = []
tweet_count = len(tweet_IDs)
try:
    for i in range((tweet_count//100) + 1):
        end_loc = min((i + 1) * 100, tweet_count)
        id=tweet_IDs[i * 100:end_loc]
        full_tweets.extend(api.statuses_lookup(id))
    return full_tweets
except tweepy.TweepError as e:
    print(e)
    print('Something went wrong, quitting...')
```

I tried to get HTTP status but it didn't work.

How can I know the tweet ID which is deleted?

Comment: kindly show the work done till now, or snippet of code.

Comment: updated my code

Answer (score 1):

In v1.1 of the API, Twitter returns [response code 144](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/response-codes) alongside HTTP 404 when a Tweet has been deleted.